# Grabar datos "date" en Mysql+PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY, pero no consigo que se añada en la bbdd.
En codigo PHP tengo:

```
$nid = $_POST['nid'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

$query = "INSERT INTO users(`nid`,`first_name`,`birthday`) VALUES('$nid','$first_name','$birthday')";
```

Es posible con la query definir el formato o previamente con php tengo que cambiar el formato?

Comment: depende del formato de fecha, que definiste en tu base de datos; es decir si en tu base de datos el tipo de dato es date entonces solo aceptará para guardar en el formato YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: si. Lo tengo como date y me lo graba en YYYY-MM-DD, pero en el frontend como lo controlo? Quiero que el usuario me ponga DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: No cometas nunca el **error** de intentar guardar una fecha en formato `DD-MM-YYYY` en la BD, ya que esta maneja el formato `YYYY-MM-DD`. Tu deber como programador es alimentar a la BD sin alterar la forma en que ella trabaja internamente. Si no lo haces así lo pagarías muy caro. Entonces, lo correcto es transformar la entrada del usuario en un formato válido para la BD: **`$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $birthday)->format('Y-m-d');`**  y **usar la variable `$fecha` en en el `INSERT`**

Comment: si. lo que quiereo es que 'birthday' se le pase en el frontend el dd-mm-yyyy pero lo grabe en bbdd como yyy-mm-dd

Comment: Con esto lo harías: *Paso 1:* convertir a un formato válido para la BD: **`$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $birthday)->format('Y-m-d');`**  *Paso 2*: Usar la variable `$fecha` en el INSERT: **`$query = "INSERT INTO users(`nid`,`first_name`,`birthday`) VALUES('$nid','$first_name','$fecha')";`**  PD: En un futuro, considera darle seguridad a tu consulta, ya que la misma es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Hay que tener en cuenta varias cosas:

- El usuario está introduciendo los datos en este formato:  `DD-MM-YYYY`
- Tú necesitas insertar esos datos en la base de datos en una columna del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`
- La base de datos maneja dichos campos con el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` ... y así tiene que seguir siendo.

En este caso, tu deber como programador es alimentar a la base de datos como ella trabaja internamente. Para ello, **deberás tomar la entrada del usuario y convertirla a un formato válido para la base de datos**.

Esto lo puedes hacer de varias maneras. La más adecuada sería recurrir al uso de la clase `DateTime`, usando el método [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $birthday)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Lo que se hace aquí es tomar la entrada del usuario, guardada en `$birthday`, sabiendo que dicha entrada viene en formato `d-m-Y` para crear un objeto `DateTime` y obtener la variable `$fecha` una representación de dicho objeto en un formato válido para ser introducido en la base de datos.

Si la entrada del usuario recuperada en `$birthday` es por ejemplo: `01-04-2018`, el código anterior te arrojará esto en la variable `$fecha`: `2018-04-01`. Ese será el valor que introducirás en la base de datos:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(nid,first_name,birthday) VALUES('$nid','$first_name','$fecha')";
```

**Nótese** que aquí estamos usando la variable `$fecha` y no la variable `$birthday`.

> PD: En un futuro, considera darle seguridad a tu consulta, ya que la
>   misma es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque por el tipo de dato que es date() y que lee en forma de YYYY-MM-DD; puedes hacer que el usuario lo lea de otro modo, si usas la clase DateTime del modo siguiente

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2018-04-02');
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

> Donde fecha lo puedes ajustar para que por ejemplo si es el dato que
>   proviene de la base de datos se lo formateas de ese modo al usuario y
>   ya lo lee en la estructura que deseas

De este modo no afectas el formato en el que guardas pero solo tendrías que hacer los ajustes para implementar en tu frontend de este modo; es una opción

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle un formato con php:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, en tu archivo PHP puede comprobar si la variable viene vacia o nulla sino entonces le das el formato que quieres con la clase, DateTime() y la almacenas, hayq ue tomar en cuenta el tipo de campo en la base de datos. (date, datetime, timestamp) ya que cada una tiene un formato diferente