# ¿Como cambiar el formato de fecha de Mysql a DD-MM-AAAA?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, centos7

Reciban mi cordial saludo, quisiera preguntarles como puedo hacer para que al ingresar una fecha en el formato DD-MM-AAAA se guarde en la base de datos mysql, ya que pro defecto las guarda como AAAA-MM-DD. Estoy trabjando con un servidor CENTOS 7,Mysql y PHP v7.3

Aquí una imagen como ingreso los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label"><strong>FECHA:</strong></label>

                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha">

               </div>
               </div>
```

Aquí una imagen como datatables muestra la FECHA en el formato AAAA-MM-DD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí una imagen de Mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay varias respuestas para esa misma pregunta en el sitio [Grabar datos date en Mysql+PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152075/grabar-datos-date-en-mysqlphp). Si quieres unificar el formularios en todos los navegadores, tendrás que usar un datepicker basado en JS.

Comment: Sería un grave error convertir una fecha al formato `DD-MM-AAAA` para guardarla con ese formato en la base de datos. 1º. La columna tendría que ser `VARCHAR`; 2º. El mantenimiento sería complicado; 3º. Sería propenso a errores; 4º. Tendrías que convertir/formatear constantemente los datos cuando los obtengas de la tabla, por lo dicho en 1º ... 5º. Y más complicaciones a la hora de calcular, etc. El formato `DD-MM-AAAA`es algo relativo, y **debes formatear en la salida, no en la entrada,** lo cual seria un error de lógica gravísimo.

Comment: Yo quiero que en mi datatable muestre el forma dd/mm/aaaa

Comment: El *Principio de Separación de Intereses* te sugiere no resolver un problema de presentación en la persistencia. Deberías manejar las conversiones en PHP ó javascript.

Comment: Entonces dime como seria en mi caso, dame un ejemplo mas preciso.

Answer (score 0):

del lado MySQL creo que no es viable ese es el estandar de las fechas, pero php tiene una solución, puedes capturar los datos desde MYSQL a PHP y mostrar asi

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime('2018-02-02')); // retorna: 02-02-2018
```

y desde php hasta MySQL

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('02-02-2018')); // retorna: 2018-02-02
```

Comment: pero en tu ejemplo significa que tendra que ingresar cada fecha nuevamente ? lo que yo deseo es que en mi DATAtaBLE se muestre en el formato DDMMYYYY sin afectar la base de datos.

Comment: mmm... vale si solo es mostrar puedes hacer uso de la primera sentencia para capturar la fecha de base de datos y mostrarla en datatable, bueno tambien depende como estes cargado los datos en datatable si pos JSON ajax directo o por JSON cargado desde JS o combiertes el DOM en Datable

Answer (score 0):

Para establecer tus datos en ese formato, tendrías que cambiar el tipo de dato al campo como VARCHAR(10), renunciando a las propiedades de un tipo DATE (operadores BETWEEN, ordenamiento, etc.).
Recuerda que PhpMyAdmin también es un cliente que puede configurarse para visualizar fechas en el formato DD-MM-YYYY, pero lo hace del lado del cliente, y no así del lado del servidor.